2-loop diagrams dimensional regularization with Feyncalc
I attempted to evaluate the following diagram using FeynCalc, following the method outlined by Pierre Ramond in his QFT book, but I encountered difficulties:
\begin{equation}
\Sigma(p)=\frac{\lambda^2\left(\mu^2\right)^{4-2 \omega}}{6} \int \frac{d^{2 \omega} \ell}{(2 \pi)^{2 \omega}} \int \frac{d^{2 \omega} q}{(2 \pi)^{2 \omega}} \frac{1}{\left(\ell^2+m^2\right)\left(q^2+m^2\right)\left([q+p-\ell]^2+m^2\right)}
\end{equation}
I’m specifically looking to evaluate this integral using Dimensional Regularization and the $\overline{\text{MS}}$ renormalization scheme. Does anyone have experience with this type of calculation in FeynCalc? Any tips or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

It depends on your existing skills in calculating loop integrals. Obtaining analytic results for master integrals is not an automatic procedure, it's almost an art that requires lots of experience and creativity. So don't expect to find a program where you can just hit buttons and get the formulas you need. Unless someone already invested lots of time and effort to obtain those formulas and put them inside the program.
The massless case of this integral should be doable with
https://feyncalc.github.io/FeynCalcBookDev/FCFeynmanParametrize.html
but the massive one won't go through this way.
You can find the analytic results here
https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-ph/0501132
https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-ph/0307101
but if you need only the pole, I would probably do an asymptotic expansion in m^2/p^2 using the method of regions by Beneke and Smirnov. This can be automatized to some extent, cf.
https://arxiv.org/abs/2405.14698
but you will probably need analytic results for the massive 2-loop tadpole at the very end. It's avaialbe e.g. here
https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0009029
If you want to learn more about generic techniques for calculating master integrals, there are Smirnov's book
https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/3-540-30611-0
and the more recent comendium by Weinzierl
https://arxiv.org/pdf/2201.03593
